# Navigation property of entity is not loading

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am building a reservation system. I have users in roles('admin', 'client', 'employee', 'student').

Each reservation must be associated with a user of role client, it might be assigned to user of role employee and might also be assigned to user of role student.

So in my reservation class I have properties of type User and I have marked them with [ForeignKey("AnytypeId")] attribute to hint EF for relations.

I have seen code like this at http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/

```
public class Reservation
{

    public int ReservationID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide a valid date")]
    public DateTime ReservationDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DateTime ReservationEnd { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public decimal Ammount
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public decimal? Discount { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string ServiceDetails { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]        
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    public String  PaymentMethod { get; set; }
    public string VoucherNumber { get; set; }

    public int ServiceID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual Service Service
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeID")]
    public virtual User Employee { get; set; }


    public string ClientID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClientID")]
    public virtual User Client { get; set; }


    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StudentID")]
    public virtual User Student { get; set; }


}

public class ReservationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Reservation>
{
    public ReservationMap()
    {
        this.HasOptional(r => r.Client).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        this.HasOptional(r => r.Employee).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        this.HasOptional(r=>r.Student).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Now as I run my mvc3 EF code first app database created for me on the fly with following ERD and edmx model.
[image]

Now few problems that I am having:
 1. When I am listing all the users of role clients in view their reservation property is showing always 0 even if their are reservations available in database. I don't know why this collection property marked with virtual is not loading??

Please I am stuck with this help me out here this is the last thing remaining.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems in your model. You have configured the one to many relationship in such a way that the many end(`Reservations` property) is excluded from the mapping. Hence the `Reservations` will not be loaded by EF.

The other problem is if you are going to map the `Reservations` property as the many end of the relationship, what will be the navigational property? is it `Employee`, `Client`, `Student`? Because only one of these properties can participate in the relationship with `Reservations` property.

It is not clear as to how these relationships should be modeled by your description. One way would be to have 3 collection properties.

```
public class ReservationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Reservation>
{
    public ReservationMap()
    {
        HasOptional(r => r.Client).WithMany(u => u.ClientReservations).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        HasOptional(r => r.Employee).WithMany(u => u.EmployeeReservations).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasOptional(r=>r.Student).WithMany(u => u.StudentReservations).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me if this is possible?

public class ReservationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Reservation>
    {
    public ReservationMap()
    {
        HasOptional(r => r.Client).WithMany(u => u.Reservations).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        HasOptional(r => r.Employee).WithMany(u => u.Reservations).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasOptional(r=>r.Student).WithMany(u => u.Reservations).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
    }

so that each type of user can have their reservations populated?

Comment: I have tried the code and get following error

Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(89,6) : error 0040: Type Reservation_Employee is not defined in namespace CRS.Domain.Concrete (Alias=Self).
(90,6) : error 0040: Type Reservation_Client is not defined in namespace CRS.Domain.Concrete (Alias=Self).

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.